# Excel formula to extract keys and values from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

In Excel I have repeated cells that contain the following set of key/values (this is a single cell with line breaks):

```
utmSource:Gmail; 
utmMedium:email; 
utmCampaign:Live; 
utmTerm:software; 
deviceType:desktop;
```

I would like to extract the values for each of the keys, e.g. what is the utmSource from a cell, what is the utmMedium, etc . How would a formula achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"what is the utmSource from a cell, what is the utmMedium, etc ."*

This sounds like some sort of lookup, so I'll answer this as though you want to perform a lookup in your cell (i.o.w. not extracting the whole array of values per se).

***Through Excel:***

[image]

Formula in `B3`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,":",";"),CHAR(10),";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]='"&A3&"']")
```

***Through Google-Sheets:***

[image]

Formula in `B3`:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A$1,A3&":([^;]+)")
```

---

To retrieve all information (Keys and values), you could use in `A3`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",""),CHAR(10))),":"))
```

But all depends on how you want to use the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a macro. The code below assumes that your set of key/value are in column A starting at from cell A1. It goes through the cells in column A1, then input the keys in column B and the values in column C.

```
Sub SplitKeyPairs()
    'Variables
    Dim myString As String
    Dim kpArr() As String
    Dim i, j As Integer

    i = 1
    j = 1
    
    Do
        myString = Range("A" & i)
    

        'Split the string based on the line break
        For Each keypair In Split(myString, vbLf)
            'Split the keypair value
            kpArr = Split(keypair, ":")
        
            'Copy keys on B column and values on C column
            Range("B" & j) = kpArr(0)
            Range("C" & j) = Replace(kpArr(1), ";", "")

            j = j + 1

        Next

        i = i + 1
    Loop While Range("A" & i) <> ""
End Sub
```

The key/value pairs will appear as on seen the image below.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: The values are concatenated with linebreaks in a single cell though

Comment: @JvdV I completely didn't notice that important part. Thank you for letting me know..

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio,, add some Screen Shots .

Comment: @RajeshS added image as per your request.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio,, I've also tested the code is working + 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods. One in `Text to Column` and another is `Excel formula`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

*Method 1:*

- Select source data.
- From **D**ata TAB hit **T**ext to column.
- Select option **D**elimited.
- Then at next screen select **O**thers from Delimiter's list and make `:` in the box.
- Then select **D**o not import column (skip) by selecting 1st column.
- Select cell `Q24` as **D**estination.

---

[image]

- Now hit **F**inish.

**N.B.**

- Shown method will work even text is in cell and separated by line break.
- Press `Ctrl+J` in box for **O**thers as Delimiter.

### [image]

*Method 2:*

- Formula in cell `R24`:

  `=MID(N24,FIND(":",N24)+1,LEN(N24))`

**N.B.** *You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*